# Convert string to DateTime for mysql in python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

I want to convert my date into DateTime object for MySQL.

My string format is: `Mon Aug 27 04:47:45 +0000 2018`
Expected Output: `'YYYY-M-D H:mm:ss'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most Efficient Way in Python to Convert String with Whitespaces to DateTime for MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839738/most-efficient-way-in-python-to-convert-string-with-whitespaces-to-datetime-for)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert datetime object to a String of date only in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624937/convert-datetime-object-to-a-string-of-date-only-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime
t = datetime.strptime('Mon Aug 27 04:47:45 +0000 2008', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %                                                                                                             z %Y')
t.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Refer section 8.1.8
[here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.day)

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
date_as_dt_object = datetime.strptime(dt, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
```

You can use date_as_dt_object in a raw query or an ORM. If used in a raw query pass it as a string like:

```
query = "select * from table where date >" + str(date_as_dt_object)
```

Check out this list for Python's strftime directives.
 http://strftime.org/

Comment: How So?  OP says he wants to convert my date into >>DateTime object .

Comment: You can't have the expected output in the case of datetime object, edit your answer, I'll remove the downvote

Comment: Sure. But it depends on how OP is using it against MySQL. A raw query will yield the correct results against this str(formatted_date). If its an ORM its better to pass a datetime object.

Comment: Correct, but the question says *expected format* after conversion, which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3, this solution would work -

```
from datetime import datetime
x = 'Mon Aug 27 04:47:45 +0000 2018'
x = datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(x, '%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %z %Y'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# OP '2018-08-27 04:47:45'
```

But for python 2, you might get a `ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive...`. In that case, you'll either have to use something like [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) or [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil). The table that you need to look for all these conversions can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

**Edit**: You can't have `Expected Output: 'YYYY-M-D H:mm:ss'` if you convert your datetime string to datetime object. Datetime object has it's own format. Above gives you a `string` of the format that you want

Comment: The timezone data is cut off.